# Can't Upload File to Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have a problem when I trying uploading objects to my amazon s3 bucket. It always shows error and it has s3 on the url.

> "Error executing "PutObject" on
>   "https://bucketname.s3.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/WIN_20171117_16_45_59_Pro.jpg";
>   AWS HTTP error: cURL error 51: SSL: no alternative certificate subject
>   name matches target host name
>   'bucketname.s3.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com' (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"

Here's my code for uploading images to the amazon s3

```
require "aws/aws-autoloader.php";
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$client = S3Client::factory(
    array(
      'credentials' => array(
        'key' => $key,
        'secret' => $secret
      ),
      'version' => 'latest',
      'region'  => 's3-ap-southeast-1'
    )
  );

try {
  $client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'=>$bucket,
    'Key' =>  $keyname,
    'SourceFile' => $sourcefile, 
    'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
    'ContentType' => 'image',
    'ACL' => 'public-read'
  ));

} catch (S3Exception $e) {
  // Catch an S3 specific exception.
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Side-note: These days, it is not particularly worth using Reduced Redundancy. In the Singapore region, it is charged at 2.4c/GB compared to 2.5c/GB for Standard storage. In some regions, it is actually *more* expensive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ap-southeast-1` as the region instead of `s3-ap-southest-1`.